# OSX Numbers Checking for either of two text values

Tags: macos, numbers

Using MacOS Numbers to count the number of cells containing `hello` or `world`:

| . | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello |
| 2 | world |
| 3 | hello world |
| 4 | world world |
| 5 | world hello |
| 6 | world bye |
| 7 | hello flynt |

The result I'm expecting is 7.

I'm lost trying to figure out formulas :

COUNTIF(A1:A7;"*hello*")+COUNTIF(A1:A7;"*world*") will return 9.

COUNTIFS(A1:A7;"*hello*";A1:A7;"*world*") will return 2

Is there a simple way to do this like in unix

```bsh
grep -e hello -e world /tmp/test
1|hello
2|world
3|hello world
4|world world
5|world hello
6|world bye
7|hello flynt

grep -e hello -e world /tmp/test | wc -l
7
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You actually have the answer there. Take the difference of the two formulae.

The logic is count all those having Hello + all haveing world - those having both so

```
COUNTIF(A1:A7;"hello")+COUNTIF(A1:A7;"world") - COUNTIFS(A1:A7;"hello";A1:A7;"world")
```